# Conditionally selecting credentials in withcredentials in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, credentials, jenkins-groovy

I have a jenkins stage which requires different credentials based on some parameters. The contents stays the same for each stage, the only change is the credentials, so I could achieve this by just having multiple stages with single credentials then just using those, but obviously not ideal.

I'm trying it essentially like this but jenkins doesn't like it

```
        stage('test execute') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([
                    if (params.Env == 'env1') {
                        usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'creds1', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')
                    } else if (params.Env == 'env2') {
                        usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'creds2', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')
                    }
                ]) 
            }
        }
```

I get the below error though

```
WorkflowScript: 25: unexpected token: if @ line 25, column 21.
                       if (params.Env == 'env1') {
                       ^
```

so I'm not sure if there's any way to add conditional logic to withcredentials, or if I just have to have multiple stages with essentially the same code

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by storing the `credentialsId` in an environment variable, and then using that env variable in the `usernamePassword()` statement.

```
def getDeploymentCreds(envName)
{
    switch(envName) {
        case ~/^Dev/: return 'MY_DEV_CREDS'
        case ~/^QA/: return 'MY_QA_CREDS'
        case ~/^Beta/: return 'MY_BETA_CREDS'
    }
}

// ...

script {
    env.DEPLOY_CREDS_ID = getDeploymentCreds(env.TARGET_ENVIRONMENT)
}

// ...

withCredentials([
    usernamePassword(credentialsId: env.DEPLOY_CREDS_ID, passwordVariable: 'DEPLOY_PASS', usernameVariable: 'DEPLOY_USER')
])
```